# Beginning web app dev - looking for direction regarding handling sensitive data

Tags: javascript, security, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm teaching myself web app development (HTML, CSS, JS, React) by making a visualization app for genealogical/family history data. This is my first web app ever, and I'm learning a lot! This data would include sensitive information of my living relatives (full name, DOB, current and past city of residence, relationship with other relatives). It's just a simple matrix stored in a Google Sheet. My relatives would use the app to visualize the data and help them appreciate the historical growth of the family.

I'm now realizing how sensitive this data is. I don't see any legal issues since my relatives would be giving me explicit permission to use their data for this project. But I want to guarantee to my relatives that it's at least as safe as any other personal information they would supply to other web apps, e.g. financial transactions, banking. Since I'm new to this, I'm having difficulty determining what technology I should invest my time learning to solve this problem. From the best I can tell after research, I have three options:

1. Keep the data locally in a .csv/.xls file and learn to program my app to work offline. For my relatives to run the visualization remotely, I can send the file via email and direct them to download the app.
2. Google Sheets is fairly secure as long as sharing is managed well and Google accounts aren't compromised. I could quickly learn APIs and OAuth to securely integrate Sheets with my app. Additionally users would log in with their Google account and request permission from me to access the app.
3. Options 1 and 2 aren't realistic, I'm way over my head and should come back to this once I'm more practiced in Javascript, Node.js, APIs and HTML and have read/taken a cybersecurity web app course or two or dived into OWASP. Looking at the list of topics I'll need to learn (encryption, hashes/salts, auth, HTTPS, input validation, security frameworks, etc.), I'm leaning toward this option.

I guess a short way of asking this is - can I achieve this level of data security as a novice programmer, or is this an advanced topic I should return to once I've made a few web apps?

Comment: May I make an observation about your objectives? There is a saying that "If the only tool you have is a hammer, you tend to see every problem as a nail"; sometimes Google Sheets is _not_ the best tool for a project. Your task will be doubly hard **because** of the chosen framework, to say nothing of the other issues (`encryption, hashes/salts, auth, HTTPS, input validation, security frameworks, etc.`). OTOH, a framework such as `WordPress` includes protocols/tools to handle ALL of your issues _and_ you can import/export from Sheets if you wish.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you very much, looking into WordPress now!